# USB Windows 11 for TPM/SB created on non-TPM/SB system

Tags: usb-flash-drive, windows-installation, windows-11, secure-boot, tpm

What option is needed to install Windows 11 to a live persistent USB on a non-TPM/Secure Boot system, if the USB will be used on a TPM/Secure Boot system. I assume it is the Standard with TPM & Secure Boot, correct? Probably need to pay up the $99 for Pro since I have learned from experience the free 11 Home upgrade is a castrated version of Pro unable to do things Pro can do.

Comment: Windows cannot be installed to USB storage currently. Windows To Go was retired some time ago and has not been revived.

Comment: Might want to tell MS that, they are still telling that lie what you get at the end is simply a installer not a live OS if any kind. I will get it done! How bout' use Ubuntu or any other Linux OS on a live usb to make a iso of my inactive Windows harddrive and write it to a new USB as large or larger than my harddrive?

Comment: Prove it. I saw plenty of guides but they all clearly indicated you were creating the USB key in order to install Windows, not installing Windows on the key.

Comment: `"Might want to tell MS that, they are still telling that lie` Please provide a link to the page where Microsoft states that you can run Windows 11 form an USB stick/drive.